# Is that a bug for WWDC 2014 Sample Code?

Tags: swift, core-data, xcode6, wwdc

I have checked WWDC 2014 video about Changes in Core Data and I think it is great. However when I tried to use the sample code in Apple website: [Earthquakes: Using Second Core Data Stack to Fetch Data in Background](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/wwdc_2014/wwdc_2014_sample_code/usingsecondcoredatastacktofetchdatainbackground.zip)

I faced a lot of error shown. Even I tried to fix these errors but some of them I could not understand. I just wonder it is the errors made by Apple developers or the errors for my Xcode 6 beta 4.

[image]

I would appreciate much if you could check for me to make sure what happened because I really need these changes in Core Data.

Thank you so much!

Comment: no, not a bug. the language's syntax has been changed only – you can read more about the latest compiler here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/xc6_release_notes/xc6_release_notes.html

Answer (score 3):

As you know Swift is still in beta. The sample project that you have mentioned above is not build using the latest swift version beta 4. They have made lot of changes from beta to beta. The compiler error shown will help you to fix those error's. You can even check the changes in beta 4 [here](http://adcdownload.apple.com//Developer_Tools/xcode_6_beta_4_o2p8fz/xcode_6_beta_4_release_notes.pdf)

Comment: Thank you but I don't think it is because of beta version. For example, as in the picture I saw 'NSArray cannot be implicitly downcast to NSDictionary' or 'has no initializers'. I think these errors are not related to version of Swift.

Comment: Array declaration is changed in beta 4. May be due to that its coming